# Writing Computed Values to output CSV file

Tags: java, csv, file-io

My code currently picks up values from  csv file and performs scientific computations and generates multiple output files , with output values separated by semicolon...

method in which the values are written in output is described below

```
public void writeDosesTable(String p)// writing the dose table
    {

        {
            PrintStream  fos;


            try
            {
                fos=new PrintStream(new File(p));



                String s;
                for(int j=0;j<nz;j++)
                {
                    s="";

                    for(int i=0;i<nx;i++)
                    {

                        s+=det_els.get(j+i*nz).getDose()+";";// comma separated or Semicolon separated mentioned here
                    }
                    fos.println(s);
                    // prints out the stream of  values in Doses table separated by Semicolon
                }
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //finally 
            //{fos.close();}
        }
    }
```

To this output generated files, I would like to add few more things

1. Add text and also some computational  outputs

The text that i would like to add for every output file is

"CONFIGURATION A+B";PSD_MAP;MAX_DOSE;CSD(95%)

in the place of  MAX_DOSE and CSD..I would like to append values of MAX_DOSE and CSD for each output generated.

I have written the code for MAX_DOSE as follows

```
public double getMaxDose()
    {
        double dose=0.0;
        for(DetEl det_el:det_els)
        {
            if (det_el.getDose()>dose)
                dose=det_el.getDose();
        }
        return dose;
    }
```

In order generate CSD(95%) i have written following code

```
 /**
    * get the number of pixels with a given dose or more
    */

public int getNmbrPixDose(double dose)
    {
        int cnt=0;
        for(DetEl det_el:det_els)
        {
            if (det_el.getDose()>=dose)
                cnt++;
        }
        return cnt;
    }
```

and the method to print MAX_DOSE and CSD(95%) as follows

```
public String getReportDoseStat()
    {
        double maxdose=getMaxDose();
        String s=("Average dose:\t"+getAvDose()+"\n");
        s+=("Max dose:\t"+maxdose+"\n");
        s+=("Pixels 95% of max dose or more:\t"+getNmbrPixDose(maxdose*0.95)+"/"+getNmbrPixDose(0.0)+"\n");
        s+=("Pixels 90% of max dose or more:\t"+getNmbrPixDose(maxdose*0.5)+"/"+getNmbrPixDose(0.0)+"\n");
        s+=("Pixels 10% of max dose or more:\t"+getNmbrPixDose(maxdose*0.1)+"/"+getNmbrPixDose(0.0)+"\n");
        return s;
    }
```

Now I would use the values generated from method getReportDoseStat() and  populate the values  Output files through the method mentioned   writeDosesTable(String p) in format

"CONFIGURATION A+B";PSD_MAP;MAX_DOSE;CSD(95%) where instead of  MAX_DOSE and CSD(95%) values of MAX_DOSE and CSD(95%) will be appended for each generated output.

..CSD (95%) is Cumulative skin dose

Kindly let me know any clues how i can possibly write these values in the format expressed in my question for each output file my script generates.

Comment: This is generally bad idea to write `CSV` format such way. Use existent libraries like `OpenCSV`/`CsvWriter`.

Comment: I cannot change the code format now, sadly i have no other options than write the CSV in the format which i have described ...I was asked to do  it

Comment: There is no "special" CSV format. It is only `CSV` or something other, `not-CSV`. You will have big troubles with strings inside file which should be correctly escaped.

Comment: the Problem is not with format Specification, i can actually generate output file in CSV format, my question has to do with the process in which i can add some computed text and values to each file... as a header ( this header describes   the Configuration  of Output Dose table , MAX_DOSE, and CSD -Cumulative Skin Dose ...)